# How was row reduction used to obtain the result in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the example below, I obtained a different result for $(2)$, and don't know how to reproduce the given one. Here is my result:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 + 2r \\ -2 + r \\ -1 \\ r \end{bmatrix}$$

I verified my result with an online row reduction calculator and it seems to be correct.

How do we get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ by row reduction in the example below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your calculation, you use the last variable $d$ as the "free parameter" (you have the equation $d = r$ and then you express $a,b,c$ in terms of $r$). However, in the calculation attached from the book, they use the first variable $a$ as the free parameter. To convert your answer to the book's answer, starting with your representation of the solution, note that

$$ a = -2 + 2r = -2 + 2d \implies d = \frac{a + 2}{2} = \frac{a}{2} + 1,\\
b = -2 + r = -2 + d \implies b = -2 + \frac{a}{2} + 1 = \frac{a}{2} - 1.$$

Hence, if we use $a$ as a free parameter instead of $d$, (setting $a = r$), we get

$$ b = \frac{r}{2} - 1, \,\,\, d = \frac{r}{2} + 1. $$

It is worth emphasizing there is "nothing wrong" with your solution. It is perfectly correct and there is no need to convert it to the book's solution. Plugging your solution into the first equation, we get

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + (2r - 2) \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + (r - 2) \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + r \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is just a different parametric representation of the same line as the one written in the book's answer (verify this!).

Comment: How is it possible to set $a = r$ and also obtain $a = \frac{r}{2} + 1$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Calculemus: I've tried to be be consistent both with your solution and the book's notation but that might have been overly confusing. If you start with your solution, then $d = r$ and (say) $a = -2  + 2r = -2 + 2d$. This expresses $a$ in terms of $d$. However, we can set $a = r'$ and then express $d$ in terms of $r'$. This is the conversion between your representation of the solution and the book's representation, only that it uses the letter $r$ instead of $r'$. Also, I've had a typo which I fixed which might have caused the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the follow-up! It helps to know that my answer can be converted to the book's solution! But I'm also interested in the procedure by which they arrived at their solution. Do you know how they got to it (assuming they didn't convert from my solution to theirs, because I see no reason to)? The row reduction algorithm we've been taught (Gauss-Jordan elimination) yields my solution.

Comment: @Calculemus: I have no idea why they used the first variable as the free parameter. As far as I know, in the standard way Gauss-Jordan elimination is taught, you use the "last variables possible" as free parameters (just like in your solution).